# C# UDP multiplayer movement is choppy (not because of interpolation)

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, udp

I am coding a multiplayer game in Unity with C# sockets. I do not have any lot of experience with sockets, so I followed a tutorial to try to put something together.

My problem is with the player movement. The movement is handled like so (client authoritative): The client sends its player's position 30 times per second to the server, the server stores the position of each player, and sends back 30 times per second the position of everybody except to the client's own player. All of this is handled with UDP sockets.

What happens is that each client receives and updates the positions, but every ~3 seconds, the movement lags a way to much for a local connection, as if the packets seem to arrive at a much slower rate. Then after about 1 second, it gets back to normal, then after 3 seconds, it does that again and so on.

This has nothing to do with the way I interpolate the movement as even without interpolation, it is still noticeable.

[Here is a video showing the problem](https://youtu.be/4LPfWpWUDDo), although I feel like you don't see it a lot in this video. The position is interpolated and the jumps are just because the video is slowed down while being recorded at 60fps.

[This is the tutorial I somewhat followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_h6Ta-vxAzQ&t=756s). I followed his series from episode 1 to 5, but this is the video which handles movement. On his video, it seems that it doesn't do what I'm experiencing.

I've also tried over the internet with my friend, and it was EXTREMELY laggy, like totally unplayable, so I'm guessing it's the same issue.

Comment: Please include your code in the question! And in general yes it might happen that some component in the network delays packages for buffering

Comment: Are you using ASYNC or SYNC?  ASYNC is much smother and doesn't require any timers (sleep) which can make app run choppy.  You need to determine if the UDP is causing the choppy results or if math calculation in the code is causing the app to behave choppy.

Comment: One possibility may be due to the data not being received at a unify rate.  I would buffer one second of data before display to compensate for data not being receive at a unified rate.  The may clear up some of the choppy response.

Answer (score 0):

From google

> TCP is a connection-oriented protocol, whereas UDP is a connectionless
> protocol. The speed for TCP is slower while the speed of UDP is
> faster. ... TCP does error checking and also makes error recovery, on
> the other hand, UDP performs error checking, but it discards erroneous
> packets.

So some of your UDP got lost somewhere or got errors so no update is made at that frames.

Don't know why it sucks this much in a local connection unless you are using wifi not ethernet cable.

Also i suggest using something like Socketweaver instead of codding low level unless your goal is just to learn low level protocols.

Comment: There is very little difference in speed of UDP and TCP from a software perspective.  They both are using IP routing and only difference is the ACK which is handled by the Ethernet interface so from a software perspective they is NO difference.

Comment: is not UDP works send and forget  type? So if receiver does not receive or got error in the message it just discards? If he used tcp when packets were lost there would be errors This way he does not get errors but also no movement..
Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The probability of error or dropped messages are extremely small.  And at a rate of 30 times a second and Ethernet being 100M, I do not think it is the reason for the choppy rehavior.  I would have a different opinion if the connection was on a poof Wifi connection.